# What does VOID NTAPI mean and where can I find references for it?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I found this code and I don't understand it. I can't find references for `NTAPI`.  For me, it's defining a function called `TestForWr` but `NTAPI` is confusing.

```
VOID NTAPI TestForWr(PVOID Ad, ULONG Le, ULONG Al);
```

Comment: It looks like a calling convention. Probably the same one as `WINAPI`.

Comment: Are you including `winnt.h`? `NTAPI` is a macro definition for `__stdcall`.

Answer (score 15):

From `WinNT.h`

```
#define NTAPI __stdcall
```

> The [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) calling convention is used to call Win32 API functions.
>   The callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions
>   `__cdecl`.

Comment: :)  yes you should have posted as answer.you really(great) gave it 3 minute before me when I was compiling this.

Comment: I'm lazy... my only objective is that the OP gets the right answer, which is why I +1 :-)

Comment: No matter wherever you post, it will take same amount of database space whether its a comment or an answer. Just make it sensible with time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The prefix *NTAPI* is a Function calling convention that is used in *native mode* Programming.

Also, it is not part of a windows subsystem like *win32*.

For example, it will look something like that: `NTSTATUS NTAPI NtForceReset(PVOID Response);` .